# ajax call to another url reset JsessionId hence cannot proceed with other links

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am calling to a restAPI through `jquery.ajax` call() once it completed i cannot use my other ajax calls hence i am thrown away from the `spring security`. i noticed the `JsessionID` change upon complete the restAPI call (i used httpFox plugging for fire fox). so what ever i am doing after the rest API call i will redirect to the Login page by `spring security`. i noticed that i am not authorized user anymore. i thought if i can keep the initial 'jsessionID' and use it through my browser it will be fine. can anyone please give me some guidance how i can do it? Thanks in advance.

this is my code to the rest api

```
        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: restUrl,
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
                // load grids
                try{
                    loadBaseGrid(); //this is a jqgrid
                    //will trigger once ajax call is success. but this 
                    //will not complete successfully. becouse of the jsession ID change
                }catch(e){
                    trace('Error in loadBaseGrid -'+e);
                }
            },
        beforeSend : function(req) {
                //req.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                //req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', token);
                },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){

                    var res = xhr.responseText;
                    try{
                        //var err = JSON.parseWithDate(res);
                        trace(err);
                    }catch(e){
                        trace('Error ->'+e);
                    }

                }    
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try appending the JSESSIONID=? on the rest url in jquery

So:

```
url: restUrl="JSESSIONID=YOUR SESSION ID",
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer for this question. i was unable to figure out a solution for this one and as an alternative i called 'RestApi' from the back end. ( by using spring Rest template).it is working fine. i will do a sample and see if this is working. Thanks again. appreciate it.

Comment: It is a security risk to append jsessionid to the url.